# Weird shading on mesh after using boolean?

Tags: modifiers, shaders

As you can see below, there's some strange, slightly visible shading issues on my mesh. I looked at the normals and they're facing the right way, and I tried using an edge split modifier as well. This started happening after I extruded a circle and used the difference boolean modifier on the mesh. If you know an answer than can help me remove these weird glitches, ty! :)

[image]

Edit: Same picture in edit mode.

[image]

Comment: @metaphor_set Sorry, that didn't work, thanks though! :)

Comment: Its likely new topology created by the boolean.  Can you show the same view in Edit Mode?

Comment: @TreyHarper Added a picture. :)

Comment: If you use a Boolean Modifier, it will likely generate poor topology. The adequate topology consists of only four-sided shapes, called Quadrilaterals or Quads. To make your topology have only quads, consider some modeling tutorials.

Comment: there are a lot of tutorial about how to create holes in cylinder, etc. You'll need to clean your topology to avoid ngons and stretched tris. Also, you don't need so many vertices for the hole, for example 8 will be enough to get a clean one

Comment: Ditto what @moon boots said.  If you count the vertices surrounding the hole, you'll see you have lots of n-gons.  Check this helpful video out.  Might be exactly what you need.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci1jBOm_5NY&t=1s